# Android testing of method calling AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-testing

I need to test a method that uses `AsyncHttpResponseHandler` and check whether request is called succesfully or fails, but neither onFailure nor onSuccess is invoked. I tried annotate test method with  `@UiThreadTest` or  `@UiThread` but it still doesn't work.
Here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", sdk = 18)
public class CustomHttpClientTest extends TestCase {
    @Test
        public void getTokenTest() throws Exception {
            RequestParams reqParams = new RequestParams();
            Properties prop = TestUtils.getProperties("testAuthorisation.properties");
            ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            AsyncHttpResponseHandler handler =  new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, String response) {
                    fail();
                }
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    assert(true);
                }
            };


            String login = prop.getProperty("login");
            String password = prop.getProperty("password");
            CustomHttpClient.getToken(activity,
            activity.getString(R.string.AUTH_SERVER_ADDRESS), reqParams,
            handler, (ThreadPoolExecutor) service, login, password);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.